# How exactly does mounting drives work?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian, mount, webserver

So I am starting to add more space to my linux server, and I have one hard drive mounted to, lets say, `/mounted/drive1`. Is the directory `drive1` the only thing that's pointing to my hard drive, or is it the whole file path `/mounted/drive1`?  If I mounted a second drive to `/mounted/drive2`, when I access `mounted` or `drive2`, is it also looking at `drive1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I believe an underlying assumption in your post needs to be corrected (the post does not quite make sense).  The implication that the directory drive one points to your hard drive is incorrect as it eliminates *the key* parts of the answer which is the abstraction in the kernel.

**The directory drive1 does not point to your hard drive.**   A block device ( often represented as /dev/???? ) is exposed by the kernel.  The kernel is notified (normally using the mount command directly or indirectly via fstab), and does the appropriate mounting and grafting of the filesystem.

If you have /mounted/drive1 and /mounted/drive2 - assuming the underlying filesystems are standard ones -

- When you access /mounted you need access only to the original (root)
  filesystem.  the presence or absence or readability of /mounted/driveX is irrelevant to the ability to access /mounted
- When you access /mounted/drive1 you need access to drive1
  but not drive2.  Depending on what you are doing you will, from a
  practical pov need access the root filesystem, but only if this is
  not cached - ie things will start breaking if the root filesystem
  goes away.
- When you access /mounted/drive2 you need access to drive2
  but not drive1.

Comment: Thanks, still new and learning things about linux. I appreciate a correct and detailed answer.